# Query table using values in XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an XML column in my table and I want to use a value from the XML to filter the rows in my table.

Let table name be: `mytable` & Let column name be: `mycolumn`

Sample XML:

```
<TxMsg>
  <TxCode>sometxt</TxCode>
  <TxType>sometxttype</TxType>
  <Roads>someroads</Roads>
  <VehicleId>QWE123</VehicleId>
...etc
<TxMsg>
```

How should I query my table such that I can only see rows that contains `VehicleId = 'QWE123'`?

I am hoping to find solutions like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn.(xpath) = 'QWE123'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [exist()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type) in the where clause.

```
select *
from dbo.mytable as T
where T.mycolumn.exist('/TxMsg/VehicleId/text()[. = "QWE123"]') = 1;
```

Use [sql:variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable) if you would like to use a variable or a parameter.

```
declare @VehicleId varchar(6) = 'QWE123';

select *
from dbo.mytable as T
where T.mycolumn.exist('/TxMsg/VehicleId/text()[. = sql:variable("@VehicleId")]') = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a complete prototype of how to do that in my github repository (https://github.com/KELightsey/chamomile/blob/master/presentation/xquery_shredding_a_table).

You'll want to look at that whole example, but the "filter" is based on a cross apply from the XML column like this:

```
{
--
-- get only the log entries having a data node in any position (//* syntax)
-------------------------------------------------
SELECT *
FROM   @entry AS [entry]
       CROSS APPLY [entry].[nodes]('/*') AS [table] ( [column] )
WHERE  CAST([table].[column].[query]('fn:local-name(.)') AS [SYSNAME]) = N'log'
       AND [entry].exist('//*[local-name()="data"]') = 1; 
}
```

Of course you'll want to use a value filter something like:

```
{
--
-- get only the log entries having a data node in any position (//* syntax)
-------------------------------------------------
SELECT [entry]
       , [entry].value(N'(./*/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(max)')              AS [value]
       , [entry].value(N'(./*/@application)[1]', N'sysname')              AS [application]
       , [entry].value(N'(./*/@timestamp)[1]', N'datetime')               AS [timestamp]
       , [entry].query(N'(./*/data/*)[1]')                                AS [data]
       , [entry].value(N'(./*/special_note/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(max)') AS [special_note]
FROM   @entry AS [entry]
       CROSS APPLY [entry].[nodes]('/*') AS [table] ( [column] )
WHERE  CAST([table].[column].[query]('fn:local-name(.)') AS [SYSNAME]) = N'log'
        AND [entry].value(N'(./*/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(max)')  = 'This is a log item.';
}
```

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where mycolumn.value('/TxMsg/VehicleId[1]','nvarchar(max)') LIKE 'QWE123'
```

I hope Column 'mycolumn' is set as 'xml' data type in table 'mytable'. You need to use the 'value()' function to extract the data out of Xml. Hope this works.